# Identification of this plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification

Photographed in Rocky Point, Mexico. Any ideas about this plant? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Could you give an indication of its size? It is hard to judge with no reference. Also, when was the picture taken?

Comment: The horizontal-looking axis is notable. please provide much better descriptions (including was it a tree? or small herb?).

Comment: It  looks to me like some gymnosperm tree. Looking like *Araucaria* and *Cryptomeria* . Araucariaceae is common in southern hemisphere. Wiki article on *Araucaria* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araucaria

Comment: Was it a big tree or small herb or a young tree or a shrub? Were those leaves and axis soft or stout? What's about the size of these twigs? From at-a-glance looking the picture it looks much like Araucaria, a tall tree.

Comment: May be related one : http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35653/what-is-the-scientific-name-of-this-evergreen-plant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Not really a precise answer (and I'm not a botanist after all).]

It's likely a lycopodiophyte. Looks like a Huperzia species, but it's impossible to tell exactly from the provided photo [if the species is not familiar, of course]. Of great help would be general appearance of the plant and form of sporangia.

You can try this key: [Lycopodiaceae of North America](http://www.efloras.org/florataxon.aspx?flora_id=1&taxon_id=10527).

Comment: [Lycopodiophyta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lycopodiophyta) was definitely my first idea as well, but beyond that I have no clue.

Comment: Looks to me like a gymnosperm like *Araucaria* and *Cryptomeria*