# What is the scientific name of this evergreen plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification, taxonomy

This plant is found in India. It is an evergreen plant. Would love to know the scientific name.[image][image][image]

Comment: In which country did you make this images?

Comment: @Chris India - it says at the top ;) ... where in India might be useful too though, it's a big country

Comment: @rg255 You're right and  I should get another coffee :-)

Comment: If you could say which part of India you found the plant in, that would be helpful. I would guess that it is a conifer, but not a pine because the needles to not seem to be clustered into fascicles.

Comment: looks like *Araucaria* and *Cryptomeria*

Comment: Araucaria sp widely used as ornamental plant in warm-regions of India

Answer (score 9):

The tree in question belongs to the **[Araucariaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araucariaceae)** family,

There are multiple species of Genus **Araucaria**,

I'd place [Araucaria araucana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araucaria_araucana) on the first place, but there are multiple others:

Araucaria araucana

[image]

Araucaria luxurians

[image]

Araucaria columnaris

[image]

Araucaria subulata

[image]

Comment: Just FTR, the tree in question is not _A. auraucana_ (Molina) K. Koch. A quick image search will show you that _A. auracana_ has much larger, robust leaves.