# What is the name of this tree?

Tags: species-identification, trees

I noticed this plant growing on the Azores islands. It has a surprisingly perfect distribution of branches, which gives it the appearance of a fake decorative plant. Does anybody know what type of tree this is?

[image: the tree]
I apologise for the image, I could not find any better ones.

**Edit:** here is another image I found:

[image: a better image]

Comment: Looks like a Norfolk Island pine to me.

Comment: I agree - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araucaria_heterophylla#/media/File:AraucariaHfoliage.jpg looks very similar to the first image

Comment: Answered probably here http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35653/what-is-the-scientific-name-of-this-evergreen-plant/35676#35676

Comment: I would guess that the symmetrical distribution of branches is because it was trimmed to look like that, it's probably doesn't look like that in nature.

Comment: @CactusWoman I think that you are correct, although I did see some very symmetric trees growing in wild habitats.

Comment: It's worth taking a look at the tree over Autum and Winter. You will see how dramatically its branches adapt to Winter. The conical shape of these trees has a direct relationship towards their native climate.

Comment: "Coniferous trees are very well adapted to the climatic conditions. Their slender, conical shape minimizes snow accumulation on the branches, allowing the trees to generally withstand the weight of the snow for the entire winter without breaking (Radford University 2008). The narrowness and small surface area of the needles, together with a waxy coating, allows the tree to resist the drying effect of strong, cold winds.

Comment: Keeping the needles throughout the winter allows the tree to photosynthesize on the occasional sunny, warm winter day, and to begin photosynthesizing in spring as soon as temperatures permit (Lakehead University 2007)." Extremely interesting :)